# Text over button on Android like in the Apollo Music Player

Tags: android, button, android-image, android-button

I'm a novice on the Android platform when it cames to development. However I'm going further from basic Views and I'd like to create something like the following buttons:

[image: Artists view in the Apollo Music Player]

This is what I want to achieve. I first tought that a Button with a custom background would have sufficed. However I don't know any way to make that small darker line with the text inside. All of the image reacts like a button and gets highlighted when you touch it.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [source code for Apollo](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Apollo) you can see [ArtistsFragment](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Apollo/blob/ics/src/com/andrew/apollo/grid/fragments/ArtistsFragment.java) is not made up of [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)s but rather [an inflated RelativeLayout](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Apollo/blob/ics/res/layout/gridview_items.xml) created by [a subclass](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Apollo/blob/ics/src/com/andrew/apollo/adapters/ArtistAdapter.java) of the [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) class.

Since any view can have an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) you can make any create a layout to look however you want and still have it act like a button:

```
// Or load it as an item from an existing layout.
View myView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.anything);
myView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Do stuff.
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every segment with an image could be a Layout with the background set to the appropriate image. Then, you just put the button inside of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Framelayout` or `RelativeLayout`. For example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawabele" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

        android:padding="12dip"

        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"

        android:text="your_text" />

</FrameLayout>
```